# Probability mass function of product of two binomial variables

Tags: binomial-distribution, density-function

I have two i.i.d. binomial variables $X$ and $Y$ with given $n$ and $p.$
What is probability mass function of $Z = X \times Y$? I need pmf as function
$f(Z, n, p).$

Comment: It's going to be messy to express, because the values with positive probability are all the possible products of two integers in the set $\{0,1,\ldots, n\},$ which contains a complex pattern of gaps.  Could you therefore specify the form in which you need this pmf or what you hope to use it for?

Comment: @whuber I've fixed my question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are various ways you could write the mass function of this distribution.  All of them will be messy, since they involve checking the possible products that give a stipulated value for the product variable.  Here is the most obvious way to write the distribution.

---

Let $X, Y \sim \text{IID Bin}(n, p)$ and let $Z=XY$ be their product.  For any integer $0 \leqslant z \leqslant n^2$ we define the set of pairs of values:

$$\mathcal{S}(z) \equiv \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{N}_{0+}^2 \mid \max(x,y) \leqslant n,  xy=z \}.$$

This is the set of all pairs of values within the support of the binomial that multiply to the value $z$.  (Note that it will be an empty set for some values of $z$.)  We then have:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
p_Z(z) \equiv \mathbb{P}(Z=z) 
&= \mathbb{P}(XY=z) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{(x,y) \in \mathcal{S}(z)} \text{Bin}(x\mid n,p) \cdot \text{Bin}(y\mid n, p) \\[6pt]
&= \sum_{(x,y) \in \mathcal{S}(z)} {n \choose x} {n \choose y} \cdot p^{x+y} (1-p)^{2n-x-y}.
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Computing this probability mass function requires you to find the set $\mathcal{S}(z)$ for each $z$ in your support.  The distribution has mean and variance:

$$\mathbb{E}(Z) = (np)^2
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
\mathbb{V}(Z) = (np)^2 [(1-p+np)^2 - (np)^2].$$

The distribution will be quite jagged, owing to the fact that it is the distribution of a product of discrete random variables.  Notwithstanding its jagged distribution, as $n \rightarrow \infty$ you will have convergence in probability to $Z/n^2 \rightarrow p^2$.

---

**Implementation in `R`:** The easiest way to code this mass function is to first create a matrix of joint probabilities for the underlying random variables $X$ and $Y$, and then allocate each of these probabilities to the appropriate resulting product value.  In the code below I will create a function `dprodbinom` which is a vectorised function for the probability mass function of this "product-binomial" distribution.

```
#Create function for PMF of the product-binomial distribution
dprodbinom <- function(Z, size, prob, log = FALSE) {

  #Check input vector is numeric
  if (!is.numeric(Z))     { stop('Error: Input values are not numeric'); }

  #Set parameters
  n <- size;
  p <- prob;

  #Generate matrix of joint probabilities
  SS <- matrix(-Inf, nrow = n+1, ncol = n+1);
  XX <- dbinom(0:n, size = n, prob = p, log = TRUE);
  for (x in 0:n) {
  for (y in 0:n) {
    SS[x+1, y+1] <- XX[x+1] + XX[y+1]; } }

  #Compute the log-mass function of the product random variable
  LOGPMF <- rep(-Inf, n^2+1);
  for (x in 0:n) {
  for (y in 0:n) {
    LOGPMF[x*y+1] <- matrixStats::logSumExp(c(LOGPMF[x*y+1], SS[x+1, y+1])); } }

  #Generate the output vector
  OUT <- rep(-Inf, length(Z));
  for (i in 1:length(Z)) { 
    if (Z[i] %in% 0:(n^2)) {
      OUT[i] <- LOGPMF[Z[i]+1]; } }

  #Give the output of the function
  if (log) { OUT } else { exp(OUT) } }
```

We can now easily generate and plot the probability mass function of this distribution.  For example, with $n=10$ and $p = 0.6$ we obtain the following probability mass function.  As you can see, it is quite jagged, owing to the fact that the product values are distributed in a lagged pattern over the joint values of the underlying random variables.

[image]

```
#Load required libraries
library(matrixStats);
library(ggplot2);

#Generate the mass function
n <- 10;
p <- 0.6;
PMF <- dprodbinom(0:100, size = n, prob = p, log = FALSE);

#Plot the mass function
THEME  <- theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 14, face = 'bold'),
                plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, face = 'bold'));
DATA   <- data.frame(Value = 0:100, Probability = PMF);
FIGURE <- ggplot(aes(x = Value, y = Probability), data = DATA) +
            geom_bar(stat = 'identity', colour = 'blue') +
            THEME +
            ggtitle('Product-binomial probability mass function') +
            labs(subtitle = paste0('(n = ', n, ', p = ', p, ')'));
FIGURE;
```

Comment: I think you might find it easier and more insightful to express the result in terms of the prime factorization of $z.$  BTW, the $\max(x,y)\le n$ condition is superfluous.

Comment: What is "$S(z)$"?