# Distribution of Product of Two Binomial Variables

Tags: binomial-distribution, statistical-power

Related to [Probability mass function of product of two binomial variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427815/probability-mass-function-of-product-of-two-binomial-variables)

I am doing a Power Analysis for Sample Size determination. I have two binomial distributions: `X ~ Bin(n,p)` and `Y ~ Bin(m,q).` Typically, `n` is the number of previous tests `n > 100`, and `p` is the "Success Rate/Reliability", and `m` is the proposed number of new tests `m < 15`, with `q` being the "Reduced Success Rate/Degraded Reliability" such that `q < p`.

If I was to approach the problem, it should be as easy as obtaining a critical value from `X` and finding `Beta/Power` with that critical value in `Y`.

```
 crit = qbinom( alpha, n, p)
 beta = pbinom( crit, m, q)
 power = 1 - beta
```

But the problem that arises is the huge difference between the distributions. Any critical value from `X` will essentially always yield a `Power = 1` in `Y.`

[image: Density Compare]

That's where I've seen a product of two Binomials occur. In the following:

```
 space = expand.grid(0:n, 0:m)
 i = space[,1] 
 j = space[,2]
 null.dist = dbinom(i, n, p) * dbinom(j, m, p)
 alt.dist = dbinom(i, n, p) * dbinom(j, m, q)
```

And further calculations are made to obtain power from these distributions. My concern and questions is that the product of the two binomially distributed variables forms a new distribution altogether. All I have been able to discover is that `E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)` but I've encountered a hurdle here that I can't jump.

Is the product of two Binomial Random Variables also a Binomial Random Variable? Or something new?

Comment: You can see that it's not Binomial by considering the support.  For instance, the product of two integers in the set $\{0,1,2\}$ can have the values 0, 1, 2, or 4, but never 3, whereas all (nondegenerate) Binomial$(n)$ distributions have positive chances for all the integers from 0 through $n.$  You therefore might find it more helpful to articulate your actual statistical problem rather than pursuing this question of what the product of two Binomial variables is.

Comment: The `dbinom` function doesn't return an integer, but the probability mass of that integer occurring within the distribution. i.e. `dbinom(180,200,.9) = .094` I suppose I have poor wording here though. I'm essentially multiplying the pmf of X and Y together.

Comment: @whuber is not confused about your question, he is simply telling you that the product cannot possibly be binomially distributed (by giving a counterexample in which the support does not reflect a binomial). The distribution will not have a closed form solution. Even in the special case where X and Y are independent (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution) the distribution will be difficult to compute. However, from your description it does not seem like X and Y are independent. You can easily get an empirical estimate of the pmf through simulation though.